# Woocommerce - Adding Custom Fields to Checkout & Custom Dashboard Tab

Tags: woocommerce, product, checkout, dashboard

I have an Multistep Checkout and for that reason i have created a new custom step called "Card-Data", where i want the customer to fill the inputs. This inputs should also appear on a Tab in My Account. I already created a new custom tab for My Account Dashboard.
Can you tell me please, how i can create Custom Fields in the checkout process and and make them visible in the Custom Dashboard Tab. The customer should has the possibility to change data entries on his own through the dashboard.

Many Thanks

Comment: can you share the code that you have used so far? this by adjusting your question

Answer (score 0):

```
// i use multistep checkout wizzard plugin. here i create a step, where user 
enters the card data



add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_before', 'add_visica_step');

function add_visica_step() {
$contents = '<h1>Visica Daten</h1>';
$contents .= '<div class="visica-step"> Please Enter something </div>';
echo $contents;
}


add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'one_more_link' );
function one_more_link( $menu_links ){


$new = array( 'carddata' => 'Card Data' );


$menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 1, true ) 
+ $new 
+ array_slice( $menu_links, 1, NULL, true );


return $menu_links;
}



/*
* Step 2. Register Permalink Endpoint
*/



add_action( 'init', 'add_endpoint' );
function add_endpoint() {

// WP_Rewrite is my Achilles' heel, so please do not ask me for detailed 
explanation
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'visicadata', EP_PAGES );

}
```

/*
   * Step 3. Content for the new page in My Account, woocommerce_account_{ENDPOINT 
    NAME}_endpoint
    */

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_visicadata_endpoint', 
   'my_account_endpoint_content' );
    function my_account_endpoint_content() {

```
 echo 'Here I want do display custom fields from checkout';

 }




 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' ,
```

'woocommerce_checkout_field_editor' );

```
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
 function woocommerce_checkout_field_editor( $fields ) {
 $fields['shipping']['shipping_field_value'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Field Value', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Field Value', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true
   );

  return $fields;
 }

// Display Field on Order Page, but i would like to display it on custom tab

 add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 
 'edit_woocommerce_checkout_page', 10, 1 );
 function edit_woocommerce_checkout_page($order){
   global $post_id;
   $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
   echo '<p><strong>'.__('Field Value').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_shipping_field_value', true ) . '</p>';
```